# Azure Mobile Apps saves incorrect datetime in Sqlite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to save an Entity with an ID and an DateTimeOffset in a AzureMobileServicesClient SQLite database in a Xamarin Forms application.

This work fine as long as the time stamp is non ambiguous. When we go from daylight saving to standard time there is a period a time where a time stamp can be ambiguous depending on the timezone. In 2016 in Denmark it is 2:00-3:00 AM October 30th.

I save the Entities DateTimeOffset as UTC, but it saves it as a local timestamp.

When I save an ambiguous time stamp as 2016-10-30 12:30 AM + 0:00 it comes back as 2016-10-30 11:30 AM +0:00. 
I have tested this for other time zones and it only happens with the ambiguous time during the shift from daylight saving to standard time in that particular time zone.

I have seen the issue fixed for a normal SQLite data base here: http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2015/06/28/how-to-retrieve-dates-as-utc-in-sqlite/
But because i am using AzureMobileSerives the solution don't work in this case.

In this code i initialize the AzureMobileService, save an ambiguous time stamp and then retreive it again, and write out the two times to the screen to see the different output

```
public static class SaveTimeStamp
{
    public static async Task Save()
    {
        //Init mobile service Client 
        var mobileService = new MobileServiceClient(Configuration.MobileAppsUrl);

        //init MobileService Database
        var dataStore = DependencyService.Get<IDataStore>();
        var path = dataStore.GetPath("store.db");
        dataStore.CreateFile(path);
        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);

        store.DefineTable<Entity>();
        await mobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, StoreTrackingOptions.NotifyLocalAndServerOperations).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var entityTable = mobileService.GetSyncTable<Entity>();

        //Save entity with ambiguous timestamp
        var ambiguousTimestamp = new DateTimeOffset(2016, 10, 30, 0, 30, 0, TimeSpan.Zero); //UTC: 30th of October 12:30 AM + 0:00 => DK time:30th of october 2:30 AM + 2:00

        var entity = new Entity
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Timestamp = ambiguousTimestamp
        };

        Debug.WriteLine("Saving datetime UTC: " + entity.Timestamp.UtcDateTime);

        await entityTable.InsertAsync(entity).ConfigureAwait(false);

        //Fetch saved entity
        var refecthedEntities = await entityTable.Where(e => e.Id == entity.Id).ToListAsync();
        var refecthedEntity = refecthedEntities.FirstOrDefault();

        if (refecthedEntity.Timestamp != ambiguousTimestamp)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Refecthed datetime UTC do not match: " + refecthedEntity.Timestamp.UtcDateTime);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Refecthed datetime UTC: " + refecthedEntity.Timestamp.UtcDateTime);
        }

        //output 
        //[0:]Saving datetime UTC: 10/30/2016 12:30:00 AM
        //[0:]Refecthed datetime UTC do not match: 10/29/2016 11:30:00 PM
    }
}

class Entity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Becuase this is a Xamarin application i also have some code in the xamarin.ios proejct to initlize the database.

```
//IN Xamarin.IOS  
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform.Init(); //Init Azure mobileservies on IOS Current  IOS 9.3
        SQLitePCL.CurrentPlatform.Init();

        LoadApplication(new App());

        App.ScreenWidth = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
        App.ScreenHeight = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }

    public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication uiApplication)
    {
        base.WillEnterForeground(uiApplication);
        uiApplication.IdleTimerDisabled = true;
    }

    public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication uiApplication)
    {
        base.DidEnterBackground(uiApplication);
        uiApplication.IdleTimerDisabled = false;
    }
}
```

I have tried to use a DateTime instead of DateTimeOffset on the entity and only use DateTimeKind=UTC, but I got the same result.

Comment: How do you store DateTime?  As Ticks?

Comment: That is determined by the framework; the entity class has a property Date of type DateTimeOffset. When I inspect the Sqlite database, it is saved as number of seconds since some offset.

Comment: Right, AsTicks is indeed the default setting. Just wanted to verify that. SqLite has no problems with this so it is indeed an Azure service issue.

Comment: Do you have a complete sample to share?  I'd like to take a look in context.

Comment: There were some errors in the first code, which is now fixed. The SaveTimeStamp class is not part of my application, but I wrote the class to identify the issue with saving ambiguous timestamps. I converted SaveTimeStamp  to static so I hope it contains enough information for you. Let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an already reported bug: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/131

Feel free to follow the bug.

Comment: Yes, they are related in that DateTime is stored as Local and not UTC in the Sqlite client database. Do you know if this bug is being worked on or when a fix can be expected?

Comment: It is not currently slated for a release.  I'll take a look at it this weekend and see what is involved.  It would be helpful if you had a GitHub repo with a frontend and backend with a minimal repro.  (Otherwise, I'll have to spend time producing one).  If you do, please add it to the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I am using mobile apps for an application for a customer and cannot put the entire application in GitHub.

Comment: Understood.  Without a valid repro, we will have to generate one.  That takes time, which means any fix will be delayed.