# Azure App Service - DateTime changes during Sync

Tags: c#, .net, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I'm working on an App which uses Xamarin.Forms and Azure App Service (include offline Sync).

On the client there is a piece of code like this:

```
appointment.StartDate = System.DateTime.Now;
```

Let's suppose appointment.StartDate is now **2017-07-05 12:00:00**.

After the user syncs the data against the server, this happens:

[image]

**Date in SqlLite database (on client):  2017-07-05 12:00:00**

**Date in server database: 2017-07-05 10:00:00**

So, I assume that Azure changes my date to UTC. That might be technically correct because you should always store UTC in a database and handle timezone conversions in the client. But unfortunately, the server database is old and stores locale dates.

How can I make the Azure store the local date from the client in the server database and not UTC?

I tried to change the WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE property in Azure to my local timezone but this doesn't work: http://www.louischarlesgagnon.com/post/azure-app-service-set-timezone-for-your-web-application

**Update 06.07.2017:**

After some further research, I found out that this is a known "problem".

Look here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/131

[Azure Mobile Apps saves incorrect datetime in Sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890764/azure-mobile-apps-saves-incorrect-datetime-in-sqlite-database)

https://forums.asp.net/t/1808269.aspx?DateTime+issues+with+Azure+c+javascript+sql+so+confused+

After reading this I was able to build a solution that resolves a part of the problem. On the client side, I'm now doing something like this.

```
 public System.DateTime? Start
    {
        get
        {
            System.DateTime? dateTime = GetValue<System.DateTime?>(_start);
            if (dateTime.HasValue)
                dateTime = System.DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime.Value, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);

            return dateTime;
        }
        set
        {
            System.DateTime? dateTime = value;
            if (dateTime.HasValue)
                dateTime = System.DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime.Value, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);

            SetValue<System.DateTime?>(_start, dateTime);
        }
    }
```

This tells Azure that the date is already in UTC and Azure does not have to convert. This works in the scenario that the System.DateTime, which was created on the client side, is now successfully stored in the server database without conversion.

**But there is now an another problem:**

When Azure returns the date stored in the server database to the client, Azure converts the "UTC date" to local date. Here is an example of the current situation:

Client Date: 06.07.2017 14:30

-> Client push date to server

Server date: 06.07.2017 14:30

-> Client gets date from server

Client date: 06.07.2017 16:30

Comment: You can convert your local time to UTC and store it!! If needed I can provide you code!!

Comment: Please check out my update in the first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But unfortunately the server database is old and stores locale dates.How can I make Azure to store the local date from the client in the server database and not UTC?

According to your description, I suggest you could store long type value DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks as your datetime not use datetime type.

This value will not be changed in your server database and it could be converted back to UTC time.

When you want to use the time, you could convert Ticks back to the datetime.

More details, you could refer to these codes:

```
    //get utc time ticks
    long i = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
    //convert back to local time
    DateTime myDate = new DateTime(i).ToLocalTime();
```

---

> I'm correct that I have to adapt my legacy applications so that they can deal with UTC?

In my opinion, I suggest you could store UTC time to your database. Then you could convert the UTC time to local time. This is right way to design your application. If there are different timezone customer, how you convert the database's local time to customer timezone's local time?

> UTC is the time standard commonly used across the world. The world's timing centers have agreed to keep their time scales closely synchronized - or coordinated - therefore the name Coordinated Universal Time.

So I suggest you could use [tolocaltime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime(v=vs.110).aspx) method to convert the UTC time to local time in your apps.

Comment: I agree. This is technically a good solution. Unfortunately there a lot of legacy applications based on the server database. I cannot just change the datatype in the server database to store UTC (ticks).  
That would mean I would have to change all applications based on this database to use the new utc date. 
I need a solution without the server database is changed

Comment: Could you please tell me which database you have used now? Azure sql database or something else?

Comment: We use a SQL Server 2016. Installed on a local machine in our company. Azure App Service is just a proxy between the app (client) and the sql server in our company.

Comment: According to your test, why you always need change the server datetime to local time? As you see, azure store the UTC time to your local server and it will auto return the local time to the client. In my opinion, this is right.

Comment: Yes of course. But this works only in the case when the client application uses the Azure SDK. There a lot of legacy applications based on the database. These applications expect the local date to appear in the database, but Azure stores the UTC date. 
Let me clarify: For my current project (Xamarin App with Azure Backend) all works perfect. But when a other application (with legacy code base, not use Azure SDK) access the date field, generates by the Xamarin App, things got weird. I'm correct that I have to adapt my legacy applications so that they can deal with UTC?

Comment: In my opinion, the right way is using UTC to store into your database. Then using DateTime().ToLocalTime() to convert  the UTC to local time. Because if your application may be used by different time zone customer, you need maintain the time be the right local time.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. I will rework my database schema and store the date in UTC.  This will be the best solution in the long term. Thank you.